# Java > Array-2 > zeroMax

Tags: java, arrays

my code only misses 5 cases and i dont know why, somebody help me.

problem

> Return a version of the given array where each zero value in the array
>   is replaced by the largest odd value to the right of the zero in the
>   array. If there is no odd value to the right of the zero, leave the
>   zero as a zero.
>
> zeroMax({0, 5, 0, 3}) → {5, 5, 3, 3}
>
> zeroMax({0, 4, 0, 3}) → {3, 4, 3, 3}
>
> zeroMax({0, 1, 0}) → {1, 1, 0}

my code

```
public int[] zeroMax(int[] nums) {
    int acum = 0;
    int i = 0;
    for( i = 0; i < nums.length;i++){
        if(nums[i]==0){ 
           for(int j = i; j < nums.length;j++){
               if (nums[j]%2!=0){
                acum = nums[j];
                break;
               }
           }
             nums[i]=acum;
        }

    }
    return nums;
}
```

Comment: Do you know which cases it's specifically failing on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are missing is, that there could be more than one odd number on the right side of your zero and you need to pick the largest one.

**Edit:** And you also need to reset 'acum'. I updated my suggestion :)

Here's a suggestion:

```
public int[] zeroMax(int[] nums) {
    int acum = 0;
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if (nums[i] == 0) {
            for (int j = i; j < nums.length; j++) {
                if (nums[j] % 2 != 0 && nums[j] > acum) {
                    acum = nums[j];
                }
            }
            nums[i] = acum;
            acum = 0;
        }

    }
    return nums;
}
```

Comment: the only thing i had to correct with my  code was the int acum, cause it was saving the odd number of the first iteration, then I added your condition, and passes all the cases. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done much more efficiently by rearranging the problem a bit.

Instead of traversing left-to-right, then scanning the integers on the right for the replacement, you can instead just go right-to-left. Then, you can store the previous replacement until you encounter a larger odd number.

```
public int[] zeroMax(final int[] nums) {

    int replace = 0; // Stores previous largest odd - default to 0 to avoid replacement

    for (int i = nums.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { // start from end
        final int next = nums[i]; 
        if (next == 0) { // If we should replace
            nums[i] = replace;
        } else if (next % 2 == 1 && next > replace) { 
            // If we have an odd number that is larger than the replacement
            replace = next;
        }
    }
    return nums;

}
```

Given your examples, this output:

```
[5, 5, 3, 3]
[3, 4, 3, 3]
[1, 1, 0]
```

Comment: thanks, thats really helpfull to keep improving my skills  :)

Answer (score 1):

```
public int[] zeroMax(int[] nums) {
  for (int i=0; i<nums.length; i++)
  {
    if (nums[i] == 0)
    {
      int maxindex = i;
      for (int j=i+1; j<nums.length; j++)
      {
        if ((nums[j]%2 == 1) && (nums[j] > nums[maxindex]))
        {
          maxindex = j;
        }
      }
      nums[i] = nums[maxindex];
    }
  }
  return nums;
}
```

**This alows you to find the index of the maximum odd number to the right, replacing the zero with the number at that index**

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is that this algorithm doesn't search for the **biggest** odd value, but for the **first** odd value in the array, that is to the right of a given value. Apart from that, you might consider creating a table for the biggest odd value for all indices to simplify your code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the possible solutions to this :)

```
public int[] zeroMax(int[] nums) {

  for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++){

    if(nums[i] == 0){

      int val = largestOddValue(nums,i);//finding largest odd value
      nums[i] = val; // assigning the odd value
    }
  }
  return nums;

}
//finds largest odd value from the index provided to end
public int largestOddValue(int[] nums,int i){

  int value = 0; // for storing value

  for(int k=i;k<nums.length;k++){

    if(nums[k]%2!=0 && value<nums[k]) // got the odd value
      value = nums[k];
  }
  return value;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    public int[] zeroMax(int[] nums) {

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length - 1; i++) {

        if (nums[i] == 0) {
            int max = 0;

            for (int j = i + 1; j < nums.length; j++) {

                if (nums[j] % 2 != 0 && nums[j] > max) {

                    max = nums[j];
                }
            }
            nums[i] = max;

            max = 0;
        }
    }

    return nums;

}
```

Comment: Here you have to check max Odd value at right side.So you should write if _italic_ (nums[j] % 2 != 0 && nums[j] > max)_italic_ . But you just write (nums[j] % 2 != 0)  only this.  Now  add this to replace 0 with maximum odd value at right side of the array.

Answer (score -1):

```
public int[] zeroMax(int[] nums) {
  int val = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    if(nums[i] == 0) {
      for(int j = i + 1; j < nums.length; j++) {
        if(val <= nums[j]) {
          if(nums[j] % 2 == 1) {
            val = nums[j];
          }
        }
      }
      nums[i] = val;
      val = 0;
    }
  }
  return nums;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public int[] zeroMax(int[] nums) {
  int[] result = nums.clone();
  for (int i = nums.length - 1, max = 0; i >= 0; i--)
    if (isOdd(nums[i])) max = Math.max(nums[i], max);
    else if (nums[i] == 0) result[i] = max;
  return result;
}
boolean isOdd(int num) { return (num & 1) == 1; }
```

We iterate backwards, always storing the biggest encountered odd number (or `0`, if none was found) in `max`.

When we find a `0`, we simply override it with `max`.

The input is untouched to avoid ruining somebody else's input.

Answer (score -2):

Here is the code which works for every input. Try this on your IDE

```
public int[] m1(int a[]){
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if(a[i]!=0){
            continue;
        }
        else if(a[i]==0){
            j=i;
            while(j<a.length){
                if(a[j] % 2 != 0){
                    if(a[i]<=a[j]){
                        a[i] = a[j];
                        j++;
                    }
                    else{
                    j++;
                    continue;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    j++;
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```