# Java > Array-2 > zeroMax codingBat why we need to reset the int variable maxOdd

Tags: java, arrays

The code I used is referenced to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30856244/java-array-2-zeromax), I can't seem to understand why does it need to reset **int maxOdd.** below is the code that I used.

```
public int[] zeroMax(int[] nums) {
   int end = nums.length-1;
   int maxOdd = 0;
   for(int i =0;i <= end;i++){
     if(nums[i] == 0){
        for(int j = i;j < end;j++){
           if(nums[j+1]%2 == 1 && nums[j+1] > maxOdd){
              maxOdd = nums[j+1];
              nums[i] = maxOdd;
           }
        }
     }
     maxOdd = 0;
  }
  return nums;
}
```

when I remove **int maxOdd**, it has errors.

**Error:**

**Correct** :zeroMax([0, 5, 0, 3]) →[5, 5, 3, 3]

**My Error** :zeroMax([0, 5, 0, 3]) →[5, 5, 0, 3]

**Correct** :zeroMax([0, 4, 0, 3]) → [3, 4, 3, 3]

**My Error** :zeroMax([0, 4, 0, 3]) → [3, 4, 0, 3]

**Correct** :zeroMax([7, 0, 4, 3, 0, 1]) →[7, 3, 4, 3, 1, 1]

**My Error** :zeroMax([7, 0, 4, 3, 0, 1]) →[7, 3, 4, 3, 0, 1]

Comment: `"an error"` - we don't like guessing about the errors, we like the specific ones which only can be fixed.

Comment: Are you asking why the `int maxOdd = 0;` statement is required?

Comment: Yes @Eran why is it required, and why is it not inside the second for loop. Thanks

Comment: By "second for loop" do you mean the inner or the outer loop? You can declare it inside the outer for loop.

Comment: Sorry for that @Nikolas , I have edited my post thanks.

Comment: @Eran , the inner for loop that contains j.

Comment: The inner loop computes the value of `maxOdd`, but the initial value of that variable must be reset before each iteration of the inner loop.

Comment: @Eran , why do we need to do that, isn't it that I already declared **maxOdd** at 0 from the beginning

Comment: @Milze consider `[0, 5, 0, 3]` - for the first 0, maxOdd will be 5. However, for the 2nd 0 maxOdd should be 3. In order for it to be 3, maxOdd must be reset to 0 before the inner loop begins (otherwise it will remain 5 and the second 0 will not be updated).

Comment: @Eran ,Yes I get that, but I didn't know why it shows `[5, 5, 0, 3]` instead of `[5, 5, 5, 3]` on the error

Comment: @Milze that's because you only modify `num[i]` if you pass the condition `if(nums[j+1]%2 == 1 && nums[j+1] > maxOdd)`